# MVC 5 - Error on Facebook Login with business account

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, oauth-2.0, account

I'm using the default OAuth 2.0 authentication on my MVC 5 application, and I use Facebook Login.

With a personal account the login occurs without any errors, but when I login with the new facebook business account it doesn't login, throwing an exception because it can't get the external login info.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    //Exception here
    var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (loginInfo == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
    [....]
```

Does any one uses this business account and had this error? Any leads how to solve it would be very much appreciated